# iOS: Why won't dispatch_async to main thread run when application state is UIApplicationStateBackground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I was recently working on a project that involves data fetch while in the background and noticed that dispatch_async blocks dispatched to the main queue will not run.

Test Conditions:
- App has Background Fetch and Remote Notification Capabilities
- Launching via Scheme Configured to Launch via Background Fetch on an iPhone 6S Plus

Sample code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          NSLog(@"Won't run");
     });

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

          NSLog(@"I ran");

          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               NSLog(@"Won't run");
          });

          dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               NSLog(@"Won't run");
          });
     });

     return YES;
}
```

Questions:
1) Does anyone know why this is? I can't find any documentation. Admittedly I may be looking in the wrong places - so far I've checked the GCD documentation on dispach_async and done some heavy web searching.
2) Are there any other ways (preferably GCD-based) I can make async calls to the Main thread even in the background?

Edit: performSelectorOnMainThread: does not appear to work either.

Comment: dispatch_async(get_main_queue will get executed only when the UI is ready.

Comment: But why? The main thread is obviously there because application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: is running on the main thread - why only block async calls to the main thread?

Comment: That method is called on main thread, and when you put the first NSLOg in the dispatch_async, your request will be queued and it will be only get executed when the other tasks in the main thread are executed.

Comment: we don't know what other tasks are getting executed before your first dispatch_async call.

Comment: Also if you want that first NSLOg to execute immediatley, you dont have to start another queue. YOu can just use NSLOG without putting that in a disaptch_async block.

Comment: The logs were just to show what was and wasn't executed. An actual use case would be a network operation callback on a background thread needing to trigger a main thread-only operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be that I was not including the delegate method application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: in my AppDelegate. For some reason triggering a background fetch without this method implemented blocks dispatches onto the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to mark the start of background task by calling:

```
self.backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
        [application endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
        weakSelf.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
```

and when background task finishes it needs to be balanced by calling:

```
if (self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.backgroundTask];
    self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}
```